# 'querySelector' on 'Document' is not a valid selector error raised even though id's of divs seem fine

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to add styles via Javascript. For some reason unknown to me, I am getting an error that says my query selector is not a valid selector, even though my ids look correct. Can someone please help me to understand what is going wrong with my code?

```js
var currentRow;
var rowCol;
for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    var x = i.toString();
    currentRow = document.querySelector("#0");
    for(let j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        y = j.toString();
        rowCol = currentRow.querySelector("#" + x + y);
        if(i == 1)
        {
            rowCol.style.border = "5px 'solid black'";
            rowCol.style.border = "5px 'solid black'";
        } 
        if(j == 0 || j == 1)
        {
          rowCol.style.border = "5px 'solid black'";
        }
    }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./tictactoe.css">
</head>
<body>
   <script src="tictactoe.js"></script>
    <div class= "header">
    </div>

    <div class= "main">
        <div id = '0'>
            <div id = "00">x</div>
            <div id = "01">x</div>
            <div id = "02">x</div>
        </div>
        <div id = "1">
            <div id = "10">x</div>
            <div id = "11">x</div>
            <div id = "12">x</div>
        </div>
        <div class = "2">
            <div id = "20">x</div>
            <div id = "21">x</div>
            <div id = "22">x</div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your script is included in the `head` and executed before the body of the HTML document is parsed, so the elements don't exist yet. Move the script to just before the closing `body` tag.

Comment: @CertainPerformance You've closed the question for the wrong reason. `id`s are allowed to start with numbers in HTML5 (you've posted a link to the HTML4 rules). That's not the problem here.

Comment: I did that and am still getting the same error

Comment: @ScottMarcus Oh, thanks, my bad. Interesting. Maybe it's a `querySelector`-specific limitation?

Comment: @CertainPerformance It is. See my answer below.

Comment: @ScottMarcus CSS selectors still follow CSS2 rules where it was forbidden. It is the problem here, OP should escape the leading numbers.

Comment: @Kaiido It's simpler (and faster usually) to use `.getElementById` because most browsers optimize access to elements with `id`s, so searching with `.getElementById` leverages that capability.

Comment: @ScottMarcus they also all use the looking-table for `#`, Chrome even using it for [id=foo]. Not a point against querySelector which offers more modularity than gEBId

Comment: @ScottMarcus i tried the code below and am now getting an error currentRow.getElementById is not a function

Comment: nevermid! fixed the problem, thank you!

Comment: @je1013 As you can see when you run my code below, no error is thrown. You are using `currentRow.getElementById()` and my code uses `document.getElementById()`.

Comment: @Kaiido It's still simpler than escaping the first char of the `id`.

Answer (score 1):

Your script is included in the `head` and executed before the `body` of the HTML document is parsed, so the elements don't exist yet. Move the script to just before the closing body tag.

Then, use `.getElementById()` to access your elements that have numbers as the first character in their `id`. `.querySelector()` won't work on those `id`s.

Also, your CSS is incorrect. Instead of:

```
"5px 'solid black'"
```

It should be:

```
"5px solid black"
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./tictactoe.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class= "header"></div>
    <div class= "main">
      <div id = '0'>
         <div id = "00">r1c1</div>
         <div id = "01">r1c2</div>
         <div id = "02">r1c3</div>
      </div>
      <div id = "1">
         <div id = "10">r2c1</div>
         <div id = "11">r2c2</div>
         <div id = "12">r3c3</div>
      </div>
      <div class = "2">
         <div id = "20">r3c1</div>
         <div id = "21">r3c2</div>
         <div id = "22">r3c3</div>
      </div>
    </div>
        
    <!-- With the script here, all the HTML above will be parsed
         and in memory so you can access the elements. -->
    <script src="tictactoe.js"></script>
    <script>
      var currentRow;
      var rowCol;
      for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++){
          var x = i.toString();
          currentRow = document.getElementById("0");
          for(let j = 0; j < 3; j++){
              y = j.toString();
              rowCol = document.getElementById(x + y);
              if(i == 1){
                rowCol.style.border = "5px solid black";
                rowCol.style.border = "5px solid black";
              } 
              if(j == 0 || j == 1){rowCol.style.border = "5px solid black";}
          }        
      }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```